# NextJS onClick not working on Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

In my `nextjs`-app I have a button component

`Button.tsx` :

```
interface Button{
   text: string
   onClick?: () => void
}

const MyButton = ({ text, onClick }: Button) => {
   return (
      <button>
        {text}
      </button>
  )
}
```

which I call on one of my pages:

```
const Page= () => {

  const doStuff = () => {
    console.log('do anything')
  }

   return(
     <div>
       <Button text="Foo" onClick={dostuff}
     </div>       
   )
}

export default Page
```

when I click the Button, nothing happens - why is that? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the click event to the button

```
const MyButton = ({ text, onClick }: Button) => {
   return (
      <button onClick={onClick}>
        {text}
      </button>
  )
}
```

And call `MyButton` from parent

```
  return(
     <div>
       <MyButton text="Foo" onClick={dostuff} />
     </div>       
   )
```